# how to generate zoom/pinch gesture using Android Monkey tool?

Tags: android, monkey

Im trying to generate zoom/pinch gesture using the monkey of android , i have tried to use the Android API MotionEvent, but found it is hard to implement the zoom/pinch events.

Can you help to tell me the correct method? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use "--pct-pinchzoom" to set the percentage of zoom/pinch events.

Example:

```
adb monkey -p $package_name --pct-pinchzoom 100 1000
```

Even through monkey help information doesn't show information about this option, but actually, you can find the "--pct-pinchzoom" in monkey source codes:
https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/Monkey.java#L789